# How can I configure sticky scroll for VS Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.85 added a feature for sticky scroll in the terminal. How can I toggle whether this feature is enabled? Or what other ways are there to configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature can be toggled on and off by using the `terminal.integrated.stickyScroll.enabled` setting. There's also a setting to control the number of sticky lines to show. Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo-file:

> ```json
> // Experimental: Shows the current command at the top of the terminal.
> "terminal.integrated.stickyScroll.enabled": false,
>
> // Defines the maximum number of sticky lines to show.
> // Sticky scroll lines will never exceed 40% of the viewport regardless of this setting.
> "terminal.integrated.stickyScroll.maxLineCount": 5,
> ```

There's also a right click / context menu item to toggle sticky scroll.